# Unable to install KAR containing camel-spring: spring beans missing

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, spring-bean

I've built an application bundled in an OSGi JAR package and now I'm trying to create a KAR file to easy deployment to Apache Karaf 4.0.8.

When I drop the KAR file there's a warning message complaining that it's impossible to resolve camel-spring due to the missing `org.springframework.beans` requirement.

```
2017-01-18 19:07:12,239 | WARN  | raf-4.0.8/deploy | KarServiceImpl | 36 -
    org.apache.karaf.kar.core - 4.0.8 | Unable to install Kar feature
        interfacturas-kar/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
    org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root:
       missing requirement [root] osgi.identity;
       osgi.identity=interfacturas-kar;
       type=karaf.feature;
       version="[1.0.0.SNAPSHOT,1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]";
       filter:="(&(osgi.identity=interfacturas-kar)
                  (type=karaf.feature(version>=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)
                                     (version<=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT))"
    [caused by: Unable to resolve interfacturas-kar/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT:
        missing requirement [interfacturas-kar/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity;
        osgi.identity=org.apache.camel.camel-spring;
        type=osgi.bundle;
        version="[2.17.0.redhat-630187,2.17.0.redhat-630187]";
        resolution:=mandatory
    [caused by: Unable to resolve org.apache.camel.camel-spring/2.17.0.redhat-630187:
        missing requirement [org.apache.camel.camel-spring/2.17.0.redhat-630187]
        osgi.wiring.package;
        filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)
                   (version>=3.2.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))"]]
```

I cannot figure why this is happening! The kar file does contain spring-beans JAR file of an appropriate version:

```
$ unzip -l interfacturas-kar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.kar
...
   614354  2017-01-11 19:07   repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.2.16.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.2.16.RELEASE.jar
...
```

The KAR file and its associated feature XML file is completely generated by `karaf-maven-plugin`, and it also lists the spring-beans dependency:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.springframework/spring-beans/3.2.16.RELEASE</bundle>
```

along with other spring related resources.

Any has some idea how to fix this? Or why is it happening?

BTW, camel-spring actually comes as a dependency of camel-cxf; I'm using blueprint for defining the routes.

Comment: KAR is not supported on JBoss Fuse. I would not suggest trying to use that.

Comment: Oh, what a pity, I was going to deploy there in the future. 

I was manually installing required features before dropping the JAR in deploy, and it works, but I'm trying to simplify the process.

What's the recommended deploy procedure in Fuse?

Comment: Read the JBoss Fuse documentation, it covers deploying to the server